# undefined columns selected in methylkit R

Tags: r

I am trying to make an object in methylkit, my data is originally from BSSeeker2 but i transformed it so that i could use it in Methylkit, first i tried using the transform that they use on this site http://zvfak.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-read-bsmap-methylation-ratio.html. 
with the code line being `pool1= methRead("pool1_v2_2018_methcall.CGmap.chr.sorted",sample.id="pool1",assembly="Pm", header=FALSE, context="CpG", resolution="base", pipeline=list(fraction=TRUE, chr.col=1, start.col=2, end.col=3, coverage.col=4, strand.col=5, freqC.col=6))`

Here i got the error Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , coverage.col) : 
  undefined columns selected. With this i used the function read.table to see if my columns were correctly placed, which they were as shown. Note the FALSE was changed into +

```
 V1   V2    V3    V4  V5   V6
1 chr1  630  631  1 FALSE 1.00
2 chr1  975  976  4 FALSE 0.00
3 chr1 1035 1036 10 FALSE 0.00
4 chr1 1071 1072 28 FALSE 0.29
5 chr1 1095 1096 16 FALSE 0.19
6 chr1 1155 1156  4 FALSE 0.75
```

After this I transformed the date to fit the amp format with a head like this using read.table

```
   V1   V2   V3  V4 V5  V6  V7
1  630 chr1  630  +  1 100   0
2  975 chr1  975  +  4   0 100
3 1035 chr1 1035  + 10   0 100
4 1071 chr1 1071  + 28  29  71
5 1095 chr1 1095  + 16  19  81
6 1155 chr1 1155  +  4  75  25
```

Here i got the error Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , 5) : undefined columns selected.
So something must be wrong with the coverage column but i could not figure out what it was, I'm new to R so i do not know if this is an error from methylkit or R itself. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: To me it seems like your data doesn't have column names. They are simply named "V1", "V2", "V3". Yet you seem to be trying using them. Like `sample.id="pool1"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, V1 etc are not the names of my column, i do not have any column names hence 'header= FALSE'. As for as I know i thought sample.id was the name of your objective hence how you want to call it. I can try to do the original file name here but i do not think that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use tab-separated file as input file (not csv or other delimiter).

Late reply, but I hope it's helpful to someone looking for an answer